# How to known if an ARM library (.so) is compatible with the raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian

I have a compiled library (without source) for a fingerprint driver. I'm sure it's an ARM compilation because the command `file mylib.so` says:

> ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
>   linked, not stripped

but if I want use them in a C++ program I have always the same error:

> error while loading shared libraries: mylib.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

this error like you see it's not very explicit, of course i have used the export command on the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the path of mylib.so.

so, How to known if a ARM library (.so) is compatible with the raspberry PI ?

**-- Edit --**

```
ldd libsgfdu03.so:
not a dynamic executable

ldd libsgfdu04.so:
not a dynamic executable

ldd libsgfpamx.so:
not a dynamic executable
```

In the SDK, with the `.so`, I have a sample C++ program to manage the driver. With two commands for compile in one makefile:

`g++  -I./ -I../include -c main.cpp` --> include one file named "sgfplib.h"

`g++ /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.so  -lpthread -lsgfpamx
     -lsgfdu03 -lsgfplib -o ../bin/arm12/sgfplibtest_fdu03 main.o  -L/home/pi/sdk/lib/arm12`

All the paths are good and no error is reported at compile time, but after `ldd` on the final executable `ldd sgfplibtest_fdu03` says:

```
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0xb6f76000)
    libusb-0.1.so.4 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-0.1.so.4 (0xb6f5a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6f3b000)
    libsgfpamx.so => not found
    libsgfdu04.so => not found
    libsgfplib.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6e6e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6dfd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6dd5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6ca6000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f83000)
```

**-- Edit same driver with debian x86 --**

```
dpkg -S libsgfpamx.so 

dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *libsgfpamx.so*

ldd sgfplibtest_fdu03 :

    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76eb000)
    libusb-0.1.so.4 => /lib/libusb-0.1.so.4 (0xb76d1000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76b8000)
    libsgfpamx.so => /usr/local/lib/libsgfpamx.so (0xb769d000)
    libsgfdu03.so => /usr/local/lib/libsgfdu03.so (0xb7632000)
    libsgfplib.so => /usr/local/lib/libsgfplib.so (0xb7623000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7536000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb7510000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb74f1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb73aa000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76ec000)
```

The same exe (but compiled for x86) does not seem to required nothing more. I'm totally lost ....

Comment: It may be depending on something that is not installed. Run `ldd mylib.so` and see what comes out

Comment: ldd mylib.so say "not a dynamic executable" :(

Comment: "not a dynamic executable" == I think you are out of luck.  `ldd` *is* a good way to tell.  Note that there is not just one ARM architecture -- the pi is ARM11, aka. ARMv6, and there is an ARMv7 (Cortex) which is not compatible.  I do not know of an easy way to tell the executables apart though.

Comment: it's the reverse.the driver is for ARM9, i guess some programs for ARM9 are compatible with ARM11. but in my case ... seem not :(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ldd foo.so` and see if there is any reasonable output.  If you get "warning: you do not have execution permission" it's because .so files are supposed to be *executable* ;).

Beyond that, I don't know if there is a simple way to check a .so for system compatibility, but I doubt you'd get the "Not found" error -- I think it really cannot find it (I also think there is a more appropriate "file format not recognized" error, and in fact that the linker might not recognize such a problem to start with). So just to be sure we are on the same page with that:

- Create a symlink in the same directory, `ln -s foo.so libfoo.so.1` -- the later is what ld will be looking for.
- Now compile a test program `g++ -L/directory/path test.cpp -lfoo`.

Does it still say "No such file or directory"?

WRT ldd output, if you get stuff like this:

```
libsgfpamx.so => not found
```

It indicates the .so is linked to another .so that cannot be found in the library path and therefore is likely not installed.  If there is reason to believe this is a common library that should be available -- eg. pthreads -- you can search the raspbian repository for packages containing that file:

```
> dpkg -S libpthread.so
libc6-dev:armhf: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so
libc6:armhf: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
```

Now we know that there are several packages with such a filename in them (libc6-dev, and libc6:armhf).  Of course pthreads is already installed anyway.  Going back to your actual problem:

```
dpkg -S libsgfpamx.so
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *libsgfpamx.so*
```

Strongly implying we are out of luck WRT a raspbian package.

Searching online for "libsgfpamx.so" and "sgfpamx" returns...nothing.  Almost certainly these are esoteric or internal things that were built along with `mylib.so`, and if you have them somewhere already you are in luck, otherwise you'll have to inquire with the people responsible for "mylib.so".

Comment: i have edited my question.

Comment: @GillesGrandguillaume : I've added to the end of my answer in reply.

Comment: so i don't understand why the same sample code work on debian ... with the same response of the command "dpkg -S libsgfpamx.so".i have edited my question. sorry for waste your time.

Answer (score -2):

The libsg libs are Secugen libs. 
You'll have to get an SDK and rebuild them for your platform.